# margin / padding not working

Tags: css, margin, padding

I have 2 main divs within a main div. I've tried adding margin and padding with a large number to test, but it just work work. Why can't I add margin / padding between them? Please help.

### HTML

```
 <div id="mainWrapper">
    
    <header class="container">
    
        <div id="nav2" class="container">
            <ul class="nav2a">
                <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Quick Search</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Advanced Search</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">English <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></p></a>
                    <ul class="nav2b">
                        <li><a href="#">French</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Italian</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Spanish</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">German</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div> <!-- end nav2 -->
        
    </header>
    
    <div class="clearfloat"></div>

   <div id="fullNav" class="container">
            
        <div id="logoSymbol">
            <a href="#">
                <img src="images/gpj-baker-symbol.png" width="54" height="51" />
            </a>
        </div>
        
        <div id="logoText">
            <a href="#">
                <img src="images/gpj-baker-text.png" width="200" height="30" />
            </a>
       </div>

        <div class="clearfloat"></div>

        <div id="mainNav">
             <ul class="nav1a">
                 <li><a href="#">Brands</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Fabrics & Wallcoverings</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Where To Buy</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Press</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        
        <div class="clearfloat"></div>

        <div class="hr"><hr/></div>
        
        <div class="clearfloat"></div>

    </div> <!-- end fullNav -->
                                    
    <div class="clearfloat"></div>

    <div id="brandContainer" class="container">
       
        <div id="breadcrumbs" class="container">
            <ul class="breadInfo">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="brands.html" class="currentPg">Brands</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div> <!-- end breadIcrumbs -->
                                    
        <div class="clearfloat"></div>

        <div class="brandList">
        
            <div class="brandImg">
                <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/442x294" /></a>
            </div>
            
            <div class="brandCopy">
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="images/gpj-baker-text.png" width="162" height="25" />
                </a>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer dui ex, pharetra a commodo maximus, luctus id ligula. Curabitur tempus arcu ac orci fringilla varius.</p>
                
                <p>Cras hendrerit, mi interdum varius luctus, nisl lectus accumsan mauris, eu tristique arcu massa et arcu. Vivamus venenatis purus blandit, placerat urna eget, faucibus mauris.</p>
                <a href="#">Explore <i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i></a>
          </div>
            
        </div> <!-- end brandList -->

        <div class="clearfloat"></div>

        <div class="brandList">
        
            <div class="brandImg">
                <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/442x294" /></a>
            </div>
            
            <div class="brandCopy">
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="images/gpj-baker-text.png" width="162" height="25" />
                </a>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer dui ex, pharetra a commodo maximus, luctus id ligula. Curabitur tempus arcu ac orci fringilla varius.</p>
                
                <p>Cras hendrerit, mi interdum varius luctus, nisl lectus accumsan mauris, eu tristique arcu massa et arcu. Vivamus venenatis purus blandit, placerat urna eget, faucibus mauris.</p>
                <a href="#">Explore <i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i></a>
          </div>
            
        </div> <!-- end brandList -->
        
    </div><!-- end brandContainer -->
```

CSS

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video {margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0; font-size: 100%; font: inherit;
vertical-align: baseline;} /* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */ article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {display: block;} body {line-height: 1;} ol, ul {list-style: none;} blockquote, q {quotes: none;} blockquote:before, blockquote:after, q:before, q:after {content: ''; content: none;} table {border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0;}

body {
    font-size: 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, a {
    font-family: "Lato", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.clearfloat {
    clear: both;
}

#mainWrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1280px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100%;
}

.container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 980px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100%;
}

header .container {
    display: block;
    float: right;
}

header #nav {
    float: right;
}

div.hr {
    border: 0.01em solid #676767;
}

#nav2 {
    float: right;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 400;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 5px 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

    #nav2 a:link,
    #nav2 a:visited {
        color: #676767;
    }
    
    #nav2 a:hover {
        color: #4284b8;
    }

    #nav2 li {
        vertical-align: middle;
        float:left;
    }

    #nav2 li,
    #nav2 li a {
        display: inline-block;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    #nav2 li a {
        padding: 5px 10px;
    }

    #nav2 li ul {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
    }
    
    #nav2 li:hover ul {
        display: block;
    }
    
    #nav2 li ul li {
        clear: both;    
    }
    
    #nav2 .nav2a {
        float: right;
    }

#fullNav {
    text-align: center;
}

    #fullNav #logoSymbol,
    #fullNav #logoText {
        display: inline;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 0 5px;
    }
    
#mainNav {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 400;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 5px 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

    #mainNav a:link,
    #mainNav a:visited {
        color: #676767;
    }
    
    #mainNav a:hover {
        color: #4284b8;
    }

    #mainNav li {
        vertical-align: middle;
    }

    #mainNav li,
    #mainNav li a {
        display: inline-block;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    #mainNav li a {
        padding: 5px 25px;
    }
        
    #mainNav li ul {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
    }
    
    #mainNav li:hover ul {
        display: block;
    }
    
    #mainNav li ul li {
        clear: both;    
    }

#footerNav {
    float: right;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 400;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 5px 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

    #footerNav a:link,
    #footerNav a:visited {
        color: #676767;
    }
    
    #footerNav a:hover {
        color: #6e8878;
    }

    #footerNav li {
        vertical-align: middle;
        float:left;
    }

    #footerNav li,
    #footerNav li a {
        display: inline-block;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    #footerNav li a {
        padding: 5px 10px;
    }
        
    #footerNav li ul {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
    }
    
    #footerNav li:hover ul {
        display: block;
    }
    
#nav3b {
    display: none;
    clear: both;    
}

#nav3b a:hover {
    display: block;
}
    
    #footerNav .nav3a {
        float: right;
    }

#breadcrumbs {
    float: right;
    font-size: 9px;
    font-weight: 400;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

    #breadcrumbs .currentPg {
        color: #676767;
        font-weight:bold;
    }

    #breadcrumbs a:link,
    #breadcrumbs a:visited {
        color: #8b8b8b;
    }
    
    #breadcrumbs a:hover {
        color: #4284b8;
    }

    #breadcrumbs li {
        vertical-align: middle;
        float:left;
    }
        
        #breadcrumbs li {
            padding: 0 .25em 0 0;
        }
        
        #breadcrumbs li:after {
            content: " | ";
            display: inline-block;
            font-size: 100%;
            margin: 0 0 0 1.25em;
        }
        
        #breadcrumbs li:last-child:after {
            content: " ";
        }
        
        #breadcrumbs li,
        #breadcrumbs li a {
            display: inline-block;
            text-decoration: none;
        }
        
        #breadcrumbs li a {
            padding: 5px 10px;
        }
    
        #breadcrumbs li a:last-child {
            padding-right: 0;
        }
        
    #breadcrumbs .breadInfo {
        float: right;
        padding-bottom: 5px;
    }

.brandList {
    display: inline;
    overflow: auto;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100%;
}

.brandImg {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 442px;
    padding-right: 8px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 50%;
}

.brandCopy {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 400;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-left: 8px;
    position: relative;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 50%;
}

    .brandCopy p {
        display: block;
        font-size: 16px;
        text-transform: none;
        line-height: 150%;
    }

    .brandCopy .currentPg {
        color: #676767;
        font-weight:bold;
    }

    .brandCopy a:link,
    .brandCopy a:visited {
        color: #4284b8;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    .brandCopy a:hover {
        color: #959595;
    }
    
    .brandCopy .breadInfo {
        float: right;
        padding-bottom: 5px;
    }

    .brandCopy a img {
        margin: 0 auto;
        margin-bottom: 16px;
        max-width: 442px;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .brandCopy p {
        margin-bottom: 16px;
        overflow: auto;
        text-align: left;
    }
```

EDIT: Full CSS added.

Comment: .brandList {
 display: inline;
 overflow: auto;
 text-align: center;
 vertical-align: middle;
 width: 100%;}



 .brandCopy .currentPg {
  color: #676767;
  font-weight:bold;
 }

 .brandCopy a:link,
 .brandCopy a:visited {
  color: #4284b8;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
 }
 
 .brandCopy a:hover {
  color: #959595;
 }
 
 .brandCopy .breadInfo {
  float: right;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
 }

 .brandCopy a img {
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  max-width: 442px;
  text-align: center;
 }

 .brandCopy p {
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  overflow: auto;
  text-align: left;}

Comment: Added the CSS to the question - it is impossible to read it from the comment

Comment: I have a feeling there is some HTML missing. Have you tried simplifying the problem? Replicating it with only two divs in a fresh HTML file to see if you can pinpoint the issue?

Comment: I tried to add the css, but it said I have too much code.

Comment: We need complete .css to solve the problem.

Comment: @somethinghere - No, not yet. I have a div that has breadcrumbs, then a new div for one brand and two separate divs inside for the image on the left and the copy on the right.

I'm kind of beginner-intermediate at this, so I'm not sure what I should do.

Comment: I don't see an HTML element for `.brandInfo`, and I don't see a CSS setting for `.brandImg`. Which divs specifically are you trying to add padding or margins to?

Comment: Maybe I don't understand what do you mean but if you simply want to insert margin between `div.brandImg` and `div.brandCopy` you can do it. Please see last line of css: https://jsfiddle.net/9t6g5yah/1/

Comment: @boszlo - Did you have to change any of my code? I was able to update the post and add more of the code. 

What I'm trying to do is have .brandImg and .brandCopy, which are in .brandList to have spacing below it. These two divs are side by side 50% each. Say if I wanted to duplicate .brandList, it won't show the margin/padding below it and I don't know why.

Comment: Nope, I did not change anything. Just added the last line of CSS. I think I know what the problem is. Please check my answer below.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

OK, so I think you've tried to add margin and padding to `.brandList` div which has `display: inline` property. Change it to `display: inline-block` and margins and paddings should work. (check: http://tympanus.net/codrops/css_reference/display/).

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much! What was it that didn't allow the margin/padding? Was it because it was reading the second .brandList in the same line, since it was inline instead of inline-block?

Comment: Cool, I'm glad I could help. Please remember to upvote and accept my answer. 'Why?' is explained in the codrops article linked above. Here's another link: http://maxdesign.com.au/articles/inline/ It will explain it even better. It's important to understand how inline elements treat properties such as width, height, padding and margins.

Comment: I also have another issue with the code. The box on the right has the content touching the top. I want it to be centered inside the box. I tried margin-top: 50%, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 4):

`margin` doesn't work on an inline HTML element. If you want to apply margin on an inline element then you must convert the target element into block level element by applying `display: inline-block` property.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.clearfix::after, .clearfix::before{
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}
```

If none of these answers work then try this by adding `.clearfix` as a class to your HTML element and then copy paste this code.